# Is there a function for derivatives and logarithms analogous to logarithms for exponents?

Tags: calculus

To put it simply: is there a function that gives the number for differentiation (for example $2$ for second derivative or $1/2$ for half derivative) or integration for a function to be equivalent to another function? For example: Which derivative of $x$ is equivalent to $2x+x^3-1$, I am not sure whether or not this actually has a solution.

Comment: What is the context? Where did you find such a problem?

Comment: If you want to know which derivative of $x$ is equivalent to $x^3 +2x-1$ then just integrate the given polynomial but to get the exact value of $C$ constant of integration. You should know some information about $function$.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, you want to know whether the equation

$$D^\alpha f(x) = g(x)$$

can be solved in general for $\alpha$, where $D$ is the differential operator and $f$ and $g$ are two functions of $x$. Broadly, the answer is no for a number of reasons, including:

1. There may not be a unique solution. For example, $D^n e^x = e^x$ is true for any positive integer $n$.
2. There may not be *any* solution. For example, $D^\alpha x^2 = e^2$ would not, to my knowledge, have any reasonable solution for $\alpha$, even if you extend outside of the positive integers.
3. If you try to extend to integral operators, you need to be careful how you define things since there's a distinct difference between definite and indefinite integrals and how they might behave in this kind of system.
4. If you also want to include fractional derivatives and integrals, then there are multiple ways to define those and they often don't behave in ways that open themselves up to algebraic manipulation (for example, it is not guaranteed that $D^{\alpha + \beta} = D^\alpha D^\beta = D^\beta D^\alpha$ if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non-integer).

There *are* things you can do, but it isn't clear whether they'd be useful for anything in particular.